# Интерполяция SQL запроса в java

Tags: java, sql

Возможно ли сделать интерполяцию строки в запросе?

```
public ClassRoom(long id, String name) throws SQLException {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    super.executeSqlStatement("INSERT INTO class_rooms (id,name) VALUES " + "(" + id + "," + name + ")",
            "Запись добавлена ");
}
```

Например, при инициализации экземпляра срабатывает функция добавления записи в таблицу, таблицы создаются, все окей, а при добавлении данной записи вылетает исключение о неверном синтаксисе.

Comment: и должно вылетать с ошибкой. Потому что сначала нужно читать документацию, и из неё узнать, что нельзя просто так взять и подставлять данные напрямую в запрос

Comment: Желательно добавить выбрасываемое исключение в вопрос

Comment: Скорее всего нужно добавить одинарные ковычки для строкого значение `"INSERT INTO class_rooms (id,name) VALUES " + "(" + id + ",'" + name + "')"`

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. Что значит "интерполяция строки"? Составить строку запроса, включив в нее значения переменных? Конечно можно, `"начало строки (" + var1 + ", " + var2 + ")"` или `String.format("начало строки (%s, %s)", var1, var2)`. Но причём тут "инициализация экземпляра" и при добавлении какой  "данной записи" вылетает исключение?

Comment: @Alexandr спасибо тебе, помогло)

Comment: @m.vokhm в другом классе, я создаю экземпляр данного класса инициализирую его переменными, срабатывает INSERT и запись добавляется в таблицу.

Comment: @Saintka Оформил ввиде ответа. Не забудьте принять ответ.

Comment: Освойте использование параметризованных запросов!

Comment: @Saintka Дополнил ответ небольшим примером по использованию параметризованных запросов

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Строковые значения необходимо обрамлять одинарными ковычками:

```
public ClassRoom(long id, String name) throws SQLException {
    super(id);
    this.name = name;
    super.executeSqlStatement("INSERT INTO class_rooms (id,name) VALUES " + "(" + id + ",'" + name + "')",
            "Запись добавлена ");
}
```

Рекомендую использовать параметризованные запросы. Вот небольшой пример:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.sql.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        try (var connection = getConnection()) {
            createTable(connection);
            insert(connection, 1, "first");
            insert(connection, 2, "second");
        }
    }

    public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:test", "SA", "");
    }

    public static void createTable(
            Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        try (Statement stmt =
                     connection.createStatement()) {
            stmt.execute("CREATE TABLE class_rooms (id BIGINT, name VARCHAR(30))");
        }
    }

    public static boolean insert(
            Connection connection,
            long id,
            String name) throws SQLException {
        try (PreparedStatement pstmt =
                     connection.prepareStatement(
                             "INSERT INTO class_rooms VALUES (?, ?)")) {
            pstmt.setLong(1, id);
            pstmt.setString(2, name);

            return (pstmt.executeUpdate() == 1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Шло третье десятилетие 21-го века. В базу продолжали уходить запросы с инъекциями... Минус от меня.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Дополнил ответ

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо.